# Pass 'Null' to a list. Null Safety

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

Trying to pass null in a list.add(null) call but unable to do this since migrating to the null safety update.

this is the error on bloc

[image]

this is the model

[image]

I have tried adding ?. to the List but having no luck in fixing this.

Comment: can you include code-snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make `StreamController`'s  dataType nullable, to add null.

```dart
final StreamController<List<ProductCategory>?> categoriesController;
```

Find more about [understanding-null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety).

Answer (score 0):

You need to change 1 line in your model class...

```
List<ProductCategory> categoryController;
```

TO

```
List<ProductCategory?> categoryController;
```

Add question mark after ProductCategory will make that list item nullable.

Answer (score 0):

try to make your list like this

```
List< yourObject ? > categoryController;
```